# Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of text/html AND text/css - No framework, pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use [color-calendar](https://github.com/PawanKolhe/color-calendar) and I am following the tutorial they have there exactly as I see in the DEMO and the documentation, as follows:

```
// js/calendar.js

import Calendar from '../node_modules/color-calendar';
import '../node_modules/color-calendar/dist/css/theme-glass.css';

let calA = new Calendar({
  id: "#color-calendar",
  theme: "glass",
  // border: "5px solid black",
  weekdayType: "long-upper",
  monthDisplayType: "long",
  // headerColor: "yellow",
  // headerBackgroundColor: "black",
  calendarSize: "small",
  layoutModifiers: ["month-left-align"],
  eventsData: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "French class",
      start: "2020-12-17T06:00:00",
      end: "2020-12-18T20:30:00"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Blockchain 101",
      start: "2020-12-20T10:00:00",
      end: "2020-12-20T11:30:00"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Cheese 101",
      start: "2020-12-01T10:00:00",
      end: "2020-12-02T11:30:00"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Cheese 101",
      start: "2020-12-01T10:00:00",
      end: "2020-12-02T11:30:00"
    }
  ],
  dateChanged: (currentDate, events) => {
    console.log("date change", currentDate, events);
  },
  monthChanged: (currentDate, events) => {
    console.log("month change", currentDate, events);
  }
});
```

and my HTML:

```
// dashboard.html
...
<div class="col">
  <div class="calendar-container">
    <div id="color-calendar"></div>
    <div id="events-display"></div>
  </div>
</div>
...
<script type="module" src="js/calendar.js"></script>
```

I tried using http-server and both the Live Server extension to check if it fixes the problem, but it persists.

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/css". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I get both of these on my devtools console

For additional info, this is my package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "color-calendar": "^1.0.7",
    "http-server": "^14.1.1"
  }
}
```

I have no idea what to do anymore... no Node.js, no framework, just javascript, html and css is being used.

Comment: Do you use a bundler like webpack? You can't load css in js without a bundler

Comment: You need to export something inside module file. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: @Konrad I don't, I didn't know I have to use it... I will look it up! Thank you, I am a little amateur with those things still.

Stefino76 I will give it a read right now!

Comment: You can still import it without a bundler through html

Comment: It worked though! I read a bit on Webpack, installed it and it worked perfectly, thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 1):

The solution brought by Konrad and Stefino76 worked.

I installed webpack on my project and configured it to accept the js and css on my .js file and now the calendar works!

All credits should go to them but I can't mark their answer as solved I think.